# Property changes are not automatically visible to Design editor

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I created a new android project with the constraint layout in IntelliJ.

I place an item (for example a button) on the screen. Then I tried to change the margin of this button.. but the changes are not automatically shown. The button is still on the same position as before.

I need to switch to the "Text" editor and then go back to the "Desgin" editor. Afterwards, the button changed its position.

Is there a way to update the "Design" editor automatically once I change one of the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about IntelliJ, but in Android Studio, there is a Preview tab which you can see on the right hand side of the "Text" part and not the "Design" part.

Build your projects in the specified IDEs to have full featured functionalities rather than using some other IDE for the same.

Hope it helps.